# Git: whole file to stdout

Tags: git

Is there a command that can take a ref and a file path, and output the full contents of the file as it was at that commit to STDOUT?

Eg. Something like this:

```
git show-me-the-file HEAD~2 some/file | do_something_with_piped_output_here
```

Comment: git cat-file -p HEAD~2:some/file

Comment: Thanks jthill - that works too. Make it an answer and I'll up-vote it.

Comment: This is what I used it for: meld <(git cat-file -p HEAD:some/file) <(git cat-file -p master:some/file); For viewing a diff of files in meld. There's probably a better way to do that too, but it seems to work well.

Comment: There is: http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-meld-for-git-diffs-in-ubuntu-hardy

Comment: @ellotheth Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @ellotheth @Joel better to setup `git difftool` to point to meld if you're ever working over an ssh terminal session (ie: without GUI.. `ssh -X` is a real pain in my experience). That way you keep a non-GUI diff tool available to `git` when you need it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`git show`

e.g.

`git show HEAD:./<path_to_file>`

Comment: the `| cat` is not needed (unless you want to prevent the pager from kicking in).

Comment: The ":" is important or you'll see a diff rather than the full file.

Comment: Do not confuse this very specific syntax with `git show HEAD -- /<path_to_file>` as I did. You'll get patch file syntax which I doubt you'll want.

Answer (score 15):

`git show <ref spec>:<path>`
for example, if you want to see a file at commit point 9be20d1bf62 you do:

`git show 9be20d1bf62:a/b/file.txt`

if you want to see file on particular branch:

`git show <branch name>:<path>`

Comment: One problem is that show (and cat-file) seems not to care about core.autocrlf=true. Output seems to always be Linux style so when using command output to compare against file on disk I always get EOL difference. I am in favor of having Linux EOL as default but it would be nice to have a flag like --respect-autocrlf that causes CRLF output when autocrlf=true and LF when when autocrlf=false.

Answer (score 4):

You want `git show` or `git archive` for this use case. The git-show command is more oriented towards sending files to standard output, though.

```
# Show .gitignore from revision before this one.
git show HEAD^:.gitignore
```

The part before the colon is a tree-ish formed according to gitrevisions(7), while the latter half is a path relative to the top of your git working tree.